# Visual Code d.ts define Promise resolve type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, visual-studio-code

having:

```
// api.js
export function getLayout(){
    return axios.get('/api/layout').then(res => res.data)
}
// api.d.ts
declare interface JSONResponse {
    meta: object,
    data: Array<Field>
}
export declare function getLayout():Promise<any> // Promise<any>.then<JSONResponse>??
```

i want VSCode to suggest the following

```
getLayout().then(json => {
    json.data // suggest data is of type Array<Fields>
})
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, then this will meet your requirement.

```
// api.d.ts
declare interface JSONResponse {
    meta: object,
    data: Array<Fields>
}

export declare function getLayout(): Promise<JSONResponse>

// client.ts
var data = getLayout().then((json) => {
    json.data;
});
```

Here is an image of the suggestion in the TypeScript playground:

[image]

Comment: I did try that the first time and i wasn't getting the suggestion. It works OK now. Strange.

Comment: it was not working because the real getLayout (getLayout(name:string):Promise<JSONResponse>) expected param name.
By calling it without a name the intellisense didnt work properly (or as i expected)